# Removing punctuations from text using R

Tags: r

I need to remove punctuation from the text. I am using tm package but the catch is :

eg: the text is something like this:

```
data <- '"I am a, new comer","to r,"please help","me:out","here"'
```

now when I run

```
library(tm)
data<-removePunctuation(data)
```

in my code, the result is :

```
I am a new comerto rplease helpmeouthere
```

but what I expect is:

```
I am a new comer to r please help me out here
```

Comment: `data<-"I am a, new comer","to r,"please help","me:out","here"` is invalid syntax in R, can you make this reproducible? Are you using `c` and these are several strings? Or this is just one long string (judging by your desired output). Either way, you can try something like `gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", data)` for starters.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's how I take your question, and an answer that is very close to @David Arenburg's in the comment above.

```
 data <- '"I am a, new comer","to r,"please help","me:out","here"'
 gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',data)
 [1] " I am a new comer to r please help me out here "
```

The extra space after [:punct:] is to add spaces to the string and the + matches one or more sequential items in the regular expression. This has the side effect, desirable in some cases, of shortening any sequence of spaces to a single space.

Comment: `gsub("[[:punct:][:blank:]]+", " ", data)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, agreed.  I try to remember the admonition against the use of regular expressions, "first you have a problem, then you write a regular expression and you have two problems." For beginners, regular expressions can be deep rabbit holes.  Did the OP want to remove tabs? Probably.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I was working on the same it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you had something like

```
string <- "hello,you"
> string
[1] "hello,you"
```

You could do this:

```
> gsub(",", "", string)
[1] "helloyou"
```

It replaces the "," with "" in the variable called string