# How to remove the apostrophe in 'Don't Know' observations in R

Tags: r, recode, apostrophe

I feel like I have tried everything, but I still cannot figure out how to remove the apostrophe in 'Don't Know' observations. My desired outcome is for the observations to say 'Dont Know.'

I have tried so many of the solutions mentioned here, but I still cannot fix it. I have multiple variables that I am struggling to change. The codes always run, but they don't actually change anything.

I have tried:

```
1. thesis <-  as.data.frame(sapply(thesis, function(doaway) gsub("'", "", doaway)))
2. for(i in 1:ncol(thesis)){
  thesis[,i] <- gsub("'","",thesis[,i])
}
3. thesis$doaway[thesis $doaway== "Don\'t Know"] = "Dont Know"
4. thesis$doaway[thesis $doaway== "Don"\'"t Know"] = "Dont Know"
5. thesis$doaway[thesis $doaway== "Don'\''t Know"] = "Dont Know"
```

Still, I am unable to do this at both the individual observations level and the whole data level.

Comment: It's possible that your apostrophe is a "fancy quote" or something like that. You could try a more general regex solution like [remove all punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29099172/903061). If you need more help, please post a few rows/columns of sample data with `dput()` so we can help find the issue, e.g., `dput(thesis[1:5, 1:3])` for the first 3 columns and 5 rows. Make sure to choose a subset that includes a couple "Don't know" entries.

Comment: `gsub("'", "", "Don't Know")` works just fine, so I agree with Gregor. Instead of typing the `'`, you can try copy-pasting it directly from the data, so it is indeed the correct character.

Comment: You can also just remove everything that isn't an alphanumeric character or a space, like discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294454/keep-only-alphanumeric-characters-and-space-in-a-string-using-gsub

Comment: @GregorThomas you are a genius thank you so much, it was just a "fancy quote" mark.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your apostrophe is a "fancy quote" or something like that. You could try a more general regex solution like [remove all punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29099172/903061):

```
gsub(pattern = '[[:punct:]]', replacement = '', doaway)
```

You could also probably copy/paste the fancy quote (or the whole "Don't Know" string with its fancy quote) into one of your other methods.